# Are python's uuid namespaces the same for everyone?

Tags: python, unique, uuid

In python's [UUID module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html), there are four namespace constants: `NAMESPACE_DNS`, `NAMESPACE_URL`, `NAMESPACE_OID` and `NAMESPACE_X500`.

Are the objects stored in these constants the same for everyone using python?

At home, I tried checking `NAMESPACE_DNS` and `NAMESPACE_URL` on two different computers and I got the exact same uuid for both, but I'm not sure I should take it as a given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the same for everyone. They're standardized values defined in [RFC 4122, Appendix C](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4122.html#appendix-C).